# how to connect to other session without password in windows 11

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

A workflow I have involves logging into a server using Remote Desktop, and then using "psexec -sid cmd" and "tscon" to connect to another (existing) session, without needing to know the password of that session's user.

It is possible for a process running as System (Local System) to make use of Task Manager or tscon to switch to another logged in session without needing to know the password of the user of that session.  If you use Task Manager or tscon as Administrator (not System), it is necessary to use the password.

This works fine in Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10.  It also works in Windows 11, **but only if** the session is using the Console, not Remote Desktop.  You can freely connect the starting session to the Console and Remote Desktop, back and forth, no logging out, not rebooting, and the needing-the-password behaviour changes depending on whether the session is via the Console or via Remote Desktop.  Previous to Windows 11, this wasn't an issue.  I also see this behaviour change in Windows Server 2016 (okay) versus a sufficiently more modern Windows Server version (not okay, needing password). I'm looking for a way to prevent the password requirement in remote desktop windows.

I realize there are several other ways to work around this.  The simplest is keeping the password of the service user at hand.  Another way would be using VNC instead of Remote Desktop.  The answer to this question requires a "proper" configuration change to Windows to restore the behaviour of previous windows versions.  A setting change in the registry or GUI is the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Thanks!

---

Here are some pretty demonstration pictures ...

using psexec to get a System command prompt (I connected to the console via VNC to get these first 3 pictures):
[image: using psexec to get a system command prompt]

using tscon to attach to another session:
[image: using tscon to switch to another session]

command prompt in newly attached session:
[image: command prompt showing service user]

if you use tscon from a remote session, this happens instead:
[image: distressing locked session image]

the previous picture is an anomalous lock screen, here is what a disconnected session looks like, rather (note the user list in the lower left and the additional buttons in the lower right):
[image: disconnected session appearance]

Comment: I think it may be as simple as security has been increased in Windows 11.  I always need a password to switch users.

Comment: Is this on a domain, in a work environment? If so, it is possible that the trust relationship could be passed along a defined chain, allowing the end result you want while still maintaining proper security. But if this is a "Workgroup" and ad-hoc home network of computers, you may not have this option easily.

Comment: @john a password is only required when remote, not when local - I can attach to another user's session without password, so long as I'm sitting at the console.

Comment: @music2myear the computer was initially not on a domain, and then I added it to a domain.  same behaviour before and after.